# How to send Login Boolean value to server in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which a login screen is visible to user and what I have to send to server is mobilenumber,password and isfirst true to server when user logging in first time and when user logout and again login I have to send isFirst false to server ,How can I achieve this problem.

Note:- I dont have to check value from shared Preference, I have to send isFirst true or false on user login first time and second time,first time is true and second time false to server using Jsons.

```
public class CLoginScreen extends Fragment {
public static String s_szLoginUrl = "http://543.168.0.110:8080/ireward/rest/json/metallica/getLoginInJSON";
public static String s_szresult = " ";
public static String s_szMobileNumber, s_szPassword;
public static String s_szResponseMobile, s_szResponsePassword;
public View m_Main;
public EditText m_InputMobile, m_InputPassword;
public AppCompatButton m_LoginBtn, m_ChangePass, m_RegisterBtn;
public ProgressDialog m_PDialog;
public CJsonsResponse m_oJsonsResponse;
public boolean isFirstLogin;
public JSONObject m_oResponseobject;
public Snackbar m_SnackBar;
public LinearLayout m_MainLayout;
public CLoginSessionManagement m_oLoginSession;
public boolean isFirstTimeLogin = true;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_screen, container, false);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    m_oLoginSession = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User Login Status: " + m_oLoginSession.isLogin(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    init();
    return m_Main;
}

public void init() {
    m_MainLayout = (LinearLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    m_InputMobile = (EditText) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);
    m_InputPassword = (EditText) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.input_password);

    m_LoginBtn = (AppCompatButton) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
    m_ChangePass = (AppCompatButton) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.btn_ChangePass);
    m_ChangePass.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    m_ChangePass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CChangePasswordScreen()).commit();
        }
    });

    m_RegisterBtn = (AppCompatButton) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.btn_Register);
    m_RegisterBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    m_RegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CRegistrationScreen()).commit();
        }
    });
    m_LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new LoginAttempt().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class LoginAttempt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        m_PDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        m_PDialog.setMessage("Please wait while Logging...");
        m_PDialog.setCancelable(false);
        m_PDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        getLoginDetails();// getting login details from editText...........
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        m_oJsonsResponse = new CJsonsResponse();
        isFirstLogin = true;
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(s_szLoginUrl);
            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("agentCode", s_szMobileNumber);
            jsonObject.put("pin", s_szPassword);
            jsonObject.put("firstloginflag", m_oLoginSession.isLogin());
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            //  httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");   ///not required
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            System.out.print("InputStream...." + inputStream.toString());
            System.out.print("Response...." + httpResponse.toString());

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            System.out.print("statusLine......" + statusLine.toString());
            ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    s_szresult = m_oJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    //String resp_body =
                    EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                }
            } else
                s_szresult = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("s_szResult....." + s_szresult);
        System.out.println("password......" + s_szPassword);
        // 11. return s_szResult
        return s_szresult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        m_PDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(response);// getting response from server
            new Thread() {// making child thread...
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    try {
                        if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {
                            m_oLoginSession.setLoginData(s_szResponseMobile, s_szResponsePassword);
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CDealMainListing()).commit();
                        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Agentcode Can Not Be Empty")) {
                            m_SnackBar = Snackbar.make(m_MainLayout, "Please enter valid mobile number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            m_SnackBar.show();
                        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Pin Can Not Be Empty")) {
                            m_SnackBar = Snackbar.make(m_MainLayout, "Please enter Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            m_SnackBar.show();
                        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid PIN")) {
                            m_SnackBar = Snackbar.make(m_MainLayout, "Invalid Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            m_SnackBar.show();
                        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Subscriber/Agent Blocked due to Wrong Attempts")) {
                            m_SnackBar = Snackbar.make(m_MainLayout, "You are bloacked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            m_SnackBar.show();
                        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {
                            m_SnackBar = Snackbar.make(m_MainLayout, "Connection Lost", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            m_SnackBar.show();
                        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Subscriber/Agent Not Found")) {
                            m_SnackBar = Snackbar.make(m_MainLayout, "User not found ! Kindly Register", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            m_SnackBar.show();
                        }

                        Looper.loop();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getLoginDetails() {
        s_szMobileNumber = m_InputMobile.getText().toString();
        s_szPassword = m_InputPassword.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How will you detect user is logging for first time? You have to use either `SharedPreferences` or `DataBase` to store and check value.

Comment: If you don't want to persist the boolean value using `SharedPreference` or **database**, then you'll have to have the logic of login count on the server. Do not send the boolean at all and then have server determine whether it's the first time or not.

Comment: All the user have their unique userId and boolenIsFirstTymLogin is false ,when particular user say userId 2, intially he is getting boolenIsFirstTymLogin=false from the response then if it is false then update this boolean value boolenIsFirstTymLogin=true on Login Click Button; Now when same user come and see boolenIsFirstTymLogin=true then you don't have to do nothing you just go to the nxt screen

Comment: give me logic code plssssss

Comment: This would require you to store the state,and its not possible to do that without using SharedPreferences or database. Ideally, this should be a server side implementation. You could make the server respond with an additional parameter which specifies if its a first time login. If this is not an option for you, you should make use of SharedPreferences.